# Employee transfers his work to another employee when leaving a company, what is the employee handing work over and that receiving the work called?

Tags: single-word-requests

In my new job, I have been asked to receive the work of an employee who has been transferred to another team, and to prepare a document stating whatever they have handed over to me.

My questions are:

1. Is there a specific name for such a document? What will I write in the title of document? How do I search Google for a sample report?
2. In the document, how shall I refer to the employee who is handing over the project files and material? I need a word for it.
3. How shall I refer to myself, that is the receiver of the project mater, in 3rd person?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably thinking of a [Handover Report](https://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Handover-in-an-Office)

I guess you can refer to the person you are taking over from as your [predecessor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predecessor)

> someone who had a job or a position before someone else, or something that comes before another thing in time or in a series

and you would be that person's [successor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/successor)

> someone or something that comes after another person or thing

[Here](https://www.un.org/ruleoflaw/files/Annex12HandoverNotes.doc) is a downloadable template of a Hand Over Report from the United Nations Peace Keeping Force.

I hope this helps! Good luck with the project.

Comment: or ***[previous] incumbent***, perhaps? If at the new desk you answer the phone to someone who still expects to speak to your predecessor, you might call him that, but I don't think I'd say *I'm his successor*. Though I might say *I'm the present incumbent [for this role where you were still expecting the previous guy].*

Comment: (Oh - and I'd be quite capable of reassuring that caller with *But don't worry about continuity. He gave me a complete Handover Report*. Even if all he gave me was a list of our customers with a tick or a cross indicating which ones were easy or difficult to deal with! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers :-D 'present guy' and "the previous guy" should work too.

Comment: @bookmanu. In your link the handover report is written and handed over by the previous incumbant to the new guy, but the OP, as the new incumbent, needs to prepare at document stating what is in the handover report, which sounds like something differenent to me (but I marked up your question before reading the link!)

Answer (score 0):

The document is called a 'transition plan', or more specifically a 'personnel transition plan' - as it describes how you are going to be transitioning the job responsibilities from one person to another.  There are all sorts of templates and examples of transition plans that you can find online.

[transition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transition) (MW)

> passage from one state, stage, subject, or place to another; change

The person who is leaving can be called a 'departing employee', and the new person taking over his/her responsibilities can be called their 'replacement' - see some sample language at this [Harvard Business Review article](https://hbr.org/2016/01/the-right-way-to-off-board-a-departing-employee?cm_mmc=email-_-newsletter-_-management_tip-_-tip_date&referral=00203&utm_source=newsletter_management_tip&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=tip_date).

Answer (score -1):

The term you're looking for might be ***knowledge transfer***.  Per Wikipedia:

> ***[Knowledge transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_transfer)*** refers to sharing or disseminating of knowledge and providing inputs to problem solving. In organizational theory, knowledge transfer is the practical problem of transferring knowledge from one part of the organization to another.

I just started editing someone's resume whose last position included the task of *knowledge transfer* to his offshore replacement.  You can do a search for a *knowledge transfer template* to find samples such as [this one from NYU](https://www.nyu.edu/content/dam/nyu/hr/documents/managerguides/KnowledgeTransferTemplate.pdf), [this one from Western University of Canada](https://www.schulich.uwo.ca/humanresources/docs/staff_orientation_resources/Offboarding%20-%20Knowledge%20Transfer%20Template%20-%2027-Oct-14.pdf), or [this article on the matter](https://www.myhubintranet.com/knowledge-transfer-template/).

If you are working on a specific situation (rather than drafting a general document to be used in multiple instances), you can simply refer to the employee you are replacing by name or by title (e.g., *the prior dog-catcher*).  If you are creating something that will be reused for this particular position in the future (when you move on), then simply refer to the position (e.g., *on Tuesdays, the dog-catcher releases the dogs in order to ensure job security*.)